# How can I delete "\n" lines from a file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, readlines

I need to check if the `.csv` file I'm working with ends with more than 1 `"\n"` line. If it finds more than a blank line, it removes them all but one.

My code is:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path


def remove_blanks():
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path: Path = Path(os.path.join(dirname, "data.csv"))
    with open(path, "r+") as op:
        lines = op.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line == "\n":
                op.write(line.rstrip("\n"))
```

The `.csv` file is something like `['01-01-2019,0,0,0\n', '18-05-2019,33,31,48\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']` and the output I'd want is `['01-01-2019,0,0,0\n', '18-05-2019,33,31,48\n', '\n']` but it doesn't seem to be able to delete any line.

Comment: Do you want to remove extra empty lines from *any* sequence, or just the one at the end of the file? (It makes a difference, because you won't know that a sequence occurs at the end of the file until you actually *reach* the end of the file, so you can't make the decision to write or skip immediately.)

Comment: @chepner I am only interested in the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this out, with this code:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path


def remove_blanks():
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path: Path = Path(os.path.join(dirname, "data.csv"))
    with open(path, "r") as op:
        lines = op.readlines()  # read lines in memory
    with open(path, "w") as op: # re-write everything from the beginning
        for line in lines:
            if line != "\n":
                op.write(line)
            else:
                continue
```

It can remove every new line in excess, no matter where it is in the file.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to keep track if you've seen *an* empty line, then write one just before you write a *non*-empty line.

```
pre = ""
for line in lines:
    if line == "\n":
        pre = line
    else:
        op.write(pre)
        op.write(line)
        pre = "\n"
op.write(pre)
```

This reduces any sequence of empty lines to a single empty line, and writes that single line just before writing a non-empty line or the end of the file. When `pre` is the empty string, writing it is a no-op.

If you want to preserve multiple blank lines in the middle of the file, build up the sequence of blank lines in `pre` as you find them, and at the end of the file, only write a single blank line (rather than `pre` itself) if `pre` is not empty.

```
pre = ""
for line in lines:
    if line == "\n":
        pre += line
    else:
        op.write(pre)
        op.write(line)
        pre = ""
if pre:
    op.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops, never rewrite the file that you are reading: it is likely not to work or at best will lead to a maintenance nightmare.

If the file is small enough to fit in main memory, this slight change in your code could be enough:

```
import os.path
from pathlib import Path


def remove_blanks():
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path: Path = Path(os.path.join(dirname, "data.csv"))
    with open(path, "r") as op:
        lines = op.readlines()  # read lines in memory
    with open(path("w") as op:  # re-write everything from the beginning
        flag = False     
        for line in lines:
            if line == "\n":
                if not flag:
                    op.write(line)
                flag = True
            else:
                op.write(line)
                # flag = False  # uncomment if you want to keep one blank line 
                                # per group of consecutive lines
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about file opening!
I've now tried it but it appears to leave 2 consecutive \n no matter what at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Counter()`.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

def remove_blanks():
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path: Path = Path(os.path.join(dirname, "data.csv"))
    with open(path, "r+") as op:
        lines = op.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            count = Counter()
            # Add 1 for every time word appears in line
            for word in line:
                count[word] += 1
            # Change the number of newlines to 1
            if count['\n'] > 1:
                count['\n'] = 1
            # Returns list with the number of elements
            line = list(count.elements())
```